# Email Activity crashes using gmail and e-mail address appears as NULL on hotmail

Tags: android, email

I wrote a small app to send an email using Action_Send.
When I start the activity by pressing the send button, I get an option to send the email using a Gmail or the Hotmail app (hotmail + SEVEN). 
If I select Gmail, the activity is force closed.
If I select Hotmail, the email address the user entered appears as NULL;

I've posted the code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
package android.development.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EmailActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    String      receipantAddress,       subject,    message;
    EditText    edtReceipantAddress,    edtSubject, edtMessage;
    Button      btnSend;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.email);

        initUIComponents();
    }

    private void initUIComponents()
    {
        this.edtReceipantAddress=   (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.edtReceipantAddress);
        this.edtSubject         =   (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.edtSubject);
        this.edtMessage         =   (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);

        this.btnSend            =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setEmailParameters()
    {
        this.receipantAddress   = this.edtReceipantAddress.getText().toString();
        this.subject            = this.edtSubject.getText().toString();
        this.message            = this.edtMessage.getText().toString();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String emailAddresses []= {this.receipantAddress};
        setEmailParameters();

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailAddresses );
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, this.subject);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, this.message);
        this.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }

    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        EmailActivity.this.finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a silly Mistake in these lines:

```
 String emailAddresses []= {this.receipantAddress};
 setEmailParameters();
```

It should be as below, because you are doing parameter setting inside the setEmailParameters().

```
 setEmailParameters();
 String emailAddresses []= {this.receipantAddress};
```

Comment: +1 - Second set of eyes always helps. That's why I love pair programming.

Comment: You saved the day, Paresh! Totally overlooked this :)

Comment: :) :) It sometimes happen when we are overloaded with works :)